# No procfile found in app image Error when deploying django app on aws ec2 instance

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2, dokku, procfile

Im using dokku to deploy my images.
Im using the following command to run the image

```
dokku ps:start <app_name>
```

but im getting the following error
[image]

I already have a procfile in my project source file:
[image]

```
web: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT lifeline.asgi:application
worker: celery -A lifeline worker -l info
beat: celery -A lifeline beat -l info
```

Im a beginner on dokku. Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Make sure your procfile named as **Procfile** not **procfile**

Comment: @AnkitTiwari it was already named Procfile

Comment: "I already have a procfile in my project source file:"                                                               did you added your procfile inside your app image

Comment: I have added a screen shot in the post. I have the file Profile just beside the manage.py file.

Comment: The image is generated from a gitlab CICD.

Comment: try to add this line inside your Dockerfile ```COPY ./Profile``` or where ever your app location is

Comment: this will add your Profile to your app image after adding given line you have to build your docker image

Comment: thanks @AnkitTiwari im testing it. I will come back with the result